# Is 3,4-diethyl-3-hexene cis or trans?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain this one, please! According to my answers sheet it is not cis nor trans. But it looks like it is cis? Why, according to my answers sheet, is this neither?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is neither because you have identical groups on either side of the double bond so there is no possibility of isomers

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. We’d like you to take the [Tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize with the site.

Answer (score 2):

As each of the groups surrounding the double bond are all identical there is no optical isomers of this molecule, as no matter which way you rotate or swap groups around you will always have the same molecule. therefore as it has no optical isomers it is neither cis nor trans

Comment: @AlkiKaka if you find that this answer satisfies your needs, consider upvoting and eventually accepting this answer so that others can find this also.

Comment: your welcome :)